# For an adder code on verilog, how do I add just 1'b1 to a 4 bit vector [3:0]A?

Tags: verilog, fpga

How do I add just 1'b1 to a 4 bit vector [3:0]A? For example, if A is 0001 and lets say B is 1'b1, I add the two and it would be 0010. B is always 1'b1, and I have to keep adding to the previous number until I get 1001, which is 9 in decimal. The attached image is a code I have written so far, but there's an error with the B, it won't let me assign a specific value to B. I'm basically trying to create something like +1 adder.[Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e6iJ.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

There is a small problem with your code that is that `B` is input while you want to force a value on it which if you think of it in hardware if you have an input port it shouldn't be forced to only 1 value inside of the module because if any stimulus outside of the module tried to force a value on `B` it will be overwritten by the value inside of the module which is `1'b1` in your case

solution:
Remove the assign statement inside of the module in line 7 and when creating the test-bench you can then force the value of B to be `1'b1` which will give you the correct behavior, if you are unfamiliar with the concept of test benches just inform me and i will elaborate more on the topic